# How to convert Address type variable to get "addr_testXXX" format address?

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, address

In plutus endpoint, I want to convert Address type value to get addr_testXXX format address.

I have try :

```
import Cardano.Api  ( SerialiseAddress (deserialiseAddress, serialiseAddress) )
  ...
-- here, var 'testAddr' is of 'Address' type
printf "ledger address is: %s"  $ show $ serialiseAddress testAddr
```

but it raised error when compiling:

```
    • No instance for (SerialiseAddress
                         plutus-ledger-api-0.1.0.0:Plutus.V1.Ledger.Address.Address)
        arising from a use of ‘serialiseAddress’
```

From google, I found this: https://github.com/functionally/mantis/blob/1cd121202452dcc1bce56ed4b4f41f0e880c9d04/src/Mantra/Wallet.hs#L56
It seem that I should convert `Address` to `AddressAny`, but don't know how to.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried converting using this: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/cardano-api/src/Cardano/Api/Address.hs#L455

Comment: I think you actually want `toAddressAny` : https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/cardano-api/src/Cardano/Api/Address.hs#L470

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo in Java:

```
public String swapAddress(String address) {
    byte[] bech = Bech32.decode(address).data;
    byte[] conv = Utils.convertBits(bech, 5, 8, false);
    conv = Bytes.sub(conv, 0, conv.length - 1);
    int networkId = conv[0] & 0x0F;
    String hrp = "";
    if (networkId == 0) {
        hrp = "addr";
        networkId = 1;
    } else {
        hrp = "addr_test";
        networkId = 0;
    }
    conv[0] = ((byte) networkId);
    byte[] data = Utils.convertBits(conv);
    return Bech32.encode(hrp, data);
}
```

You can find the convertBits [here](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/5e2e62f86844653cd21187d2a2fc1eeecfa27c09/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/core/SegwitAddress.java) and [Bech32 here](https://github.com/bitcoinj/bitcoinj/blob/44d0576ce4310a3d6f1859964e391fa8d981d409/core/src/main/java/org/bitcoinj/base/Bech32.java#L148).
For Cardano, Bech32 #152 & #153 are unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help. But I write plutus code and looking forward to haskell example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function [(1)](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-node/cardano-api/lib/Cardano-Api.html#v:makeShelleyAddress) in `Cardano.Api`,

```
makeShelleyAddress :: NetworkId → PaymentCredential → StakeAddressReference → Address ShelleyAddr
```

The resulting address of type `Address ShelleyAddr` has an instance of `SerialiseAddress` [(2)](https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-node/cardano-api/lib/Cardano-Api.html#t:ShelleyAddr) so you can use

```
serialiseAddress ∷ Address ShelleyAddr → Text
```

on it.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I am also looking at this issue as well, digging around different resources and find out 3rd Cohort PPP's week6, where Lars has demonstrated how to do it: https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-pioneer-program/blob/main/code/week06/src/Week06/Utils.hs

In particular, I just tried out it works to get the `PaymentPubKeyHash` from `Bech32 Address` through the below code snippet.

```haskell
unsafeReadAddress :: String -> Plutus.Address
unsafeReadAddress s = fromMaybe (error $ "can't parse " ++ s ++ " as an address") $ tryReadAddress s

credentialLedgerToPlutus :: Ledger.Credential a StandardCrypto -> Plutus.Credential
credentialLedgerToPlutus (ScriptHashObj (Hash.ScriptHash h)) = Plutus.ScriptCredential $ Plutus.ValidatorHash $ toBuiltin $ hashToBytes h
credentialLedgerToPlutus (KeyHashObj (KeyHash h))       = Plutus.PubKeyCredential $ Plutus.PubKeyHash $ toBuiltin $ hashToBytes h

tryReadAddress :: String -> Maybe Plutus.Address
tryReadAddress x = case deserialiseAddress AsAddressAny $ pack x of
    Nothing                                      -> Nothing
    Just (AddressByron _)                        -> Nothing
    Just (AddressShelley (ShelleyAddress _ p _)) -> Just Plutus.Address
        { Plutus.addressCredential        = credentialLedgerToPlutus p
        , Plutus.addressStakingCredential = Nothing
        -- , Plutus.addressStakingCredential = stakeReferenceLedgerToPlutus s
        }

getCredentials :: Plutus.Address -> Maybe (Plutus.PaymentPubKeyHash, Maybe Plutus.StakePubKeyHash)
getCredentials (Plutus.Address x y) = case x of
    ScriptCredential _   -> Nothing
    PubKeyCredential pkh ->
      let
        ppkh = Plutus.PaymentPubKeyHash pkh
      in
        case y of
            Nothing                        -> Just (ppkh, Nothing)
            Just (Plutus.StakingPtr _ _ _) -> Nothing
            Just (StakingHash h)           -> case h of
                ScriptCredential _    -> Nothing
                PubKeyCredential pkh' -> Just (ppkh, Just $ Plutus.StakePubKeyHash pkh')

unsafePaymentPubKeyHash :: Plutus.Address -> Plutus.PaymentPubKeyHash
unsafePaymentPubKeyHash addr = maybe (error $ "script address " ++ show addr ++ " does not contain a payment key") fst $ getCredentials addr
```

i.e. I skipped the staking credential part coz seems part of the code is deprecated, still under investigation. But the `PaymentPubKeyHash` part works fine for me.